# Removing the clip on Rotring 600

Tags: pencils, maintenance, tool-modification

I hate the clip on my Rotring 600.  Information I found online stated that you can't remove the clip without bending or breaking it.  Is there a non-destructive way to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

The clip can be removed by gently spinning it to loosen it a bit, then pushing it over the top of the pen. This removes it without damaging it, and it can be re-added by just pushing it back over the top.